# Question about $L^2$ projection while learning finite element method

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, computational-mathematics

I am sorry this problem may be too general, I know the projection, but I don't get why the function $f$ ($f \in L^2(I)$, interval $I=[0, L]$)can be plotted like a vector in this picture?

If this is hard to be answered, please provide some reference, I will read.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That picture is just a schematic to illustrate the idea that $f$ can be uniquely decomposed into two parts, one of which lying in the subspace $V_h$ and the other being orthogonal to every element of $V_h$. There’s nothing more to it than that.

Comment: Could $f$ be a curve in the figure?

Comment: @majordoctor Again, this is just a picture to provide some intuition.  It's not a literal plot.  Yes, $f$ could be any element of a vector space which is equipped with an inner product, such as an element of $L^2(I)$.